# Uninitialized Constant error for local gem during production assets precompile rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, bundler, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to integrate galetahub/ckeditor in my forums, tried to install from git in bundle but some problem as git command not detected in elastic beanstalk production even though I included git package in  .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml. Also, needed to change some parameters for using git, bundle for installing gems. So, I cloned the gem to myvendor/gems and change path to local

so in Gemfile included,

```
gem 'ckeditor', '4.5.10', :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'vendor', 'gems', 'ckeditor')
```

after deploying it installed but during assets precompile task, its not detecting module ,
In development environment everything is working fine.

eb logs error is

```
export RUBY_VERSION=2.3.1;
  export GEM_ROOT="/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0";'
  +++ export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
  +++ RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
  +++ export RUBY_VERSION=2.3.1
  +++ RUBY_VERSION=2.3.1
  +++ export GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  +++ GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  ++ ((  0 != 0  ))
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-rake-task.rb assets:precompile' webapp
  + '[' false == true ']'
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' webapp
  rake aborted!
  NoMethodError: undefined method `setup' for Ckeditor:Module
  /var/app/ondeck/config/initializers/ckeditor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => environment
  (See full trace by running task with —trace) (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```